# vector analysis - construction of example of vector field with certain constraints

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**question:** Does there exist smooth vector field $ \bf{F}$ $=(F^{1},F^{2},F^{3})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that it is not constant and that integral from this field $\bf{F}$ along any closed curve and every closed surface equals 0?

**what I alreay did?** I know that the conditions put on value of integral implies: $curl(\bf{F}$ $) = 0$ , $div(\bf{F}$ $)=0$, giving conditions:

$
F_{y}^{3}=F_{z}^{2} \\
F_{z}^{1}=F_{x}^{3} \\
F_{x}^{2}=F_{y}^{1} \\
F_{x}^{1}+F_{y}^{2}+F_{z}^{3}=0
$

Checked that $\bf{F}$ $=(x,y,-2z)$ holds the above conditions.

Can any state whether my reasoning is correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback.

Comment: Btw., I still wonder whether the vector field with the above constraints is the only one possible?

Comment: Of course not: raise to the $\;n\,-$ th power each of the three coordinates, or multiply them by any constants...

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for help. End of consideration.